# c# "Or" operator errors

Tags: c#

I am currently doing an assignment for my programming subject and we're currently focusing on input validation. 
My current issue is when checking to see if the user has inputted their gender correctly, (M, m, F or f)

I am using:

```
Console.Write("Please enter your gender (m) or (f) : ");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
        string gender = response;

        if (gender != "m" || gender != "M" || gender != "f" || gender != "F") 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error : Gender must be either : M / m (For Male) or F / f (For Female) ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);


        }
```

The console is outputting "Mistake" for absolutely anything that I enter, however, when I remove the last three parts of the condition and leave it as (gender != "M") it seems to work fine.

Comment: It should be **and** (so `&&` instead of `||`).

Comment: You could use `if (new[] { "m", "f" }.Contains(gender, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){ ... }`

Comment: Look into logic gates

Comment: Just follow your code.  What happens if the user entered "m"?  The first condition in your `if` statement `gender != "m"` will be `false`.  Because you're using or (`||`), then it continues to the next condition (`gender != "M"`) which is `true`.  Since `or` short circuits, it will enter the if block if any of the conditions are true.  In other words:  `(false || true || true || true) == true`